# Code coming back from database is showing HTML Codes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to gather some information from a database, Currently a user fills out a form and the textbox fills in html format accordingly.

The issue is when its passed to the database its saved down as this

```
<p>How would this work?</p><p><br/></p><p>I need to know, IF the HTML formatting is here</p><p><br/></p><h1>unfortunatly it may stick</h1><h4>Although it might not,</h4><p>Only time will tell, If the <b>Font </b><i>Stays </i><u>or </u><strike>not</strike></p>
```

The issue i have is when i call it do be placed back into the page it displays as the same, Rather than keeping the format.

I'm using Rails to call the DB so heres my little code to call the DB

```
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
<%= ev.details %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052906/how-to-display-content-with-raw-html ?

Comment: Damn, I'd been looking everywhere for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## html_safe

Rails by default escapes all the text to prevent any injecting and such type of attacks, if you know that the data is safe then tell rails that it is, just add `html_safe` to the string

```
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
  <%= ev.details.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

## raw

Note that `#html_safe` is a `String` helper, so it works on `String` objects, if for any reason this string could be a `nil` object, then it would raise an error `undefined method html_safe for nil`

In that case using `raw` might be safer, because it would return an empty string for `nil` instead of raising an error.

Internally `raw` calls `#to_s` then mark it the result string as `html_safe`, in the `nil` case it will convert `nil` to an empty string, then mark it as safe.

```
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
  <%= raw ev.details %>
<% end %>
```

## sanitize

You might also want to consider using `sanitize` which allows only a certain set of tags and cleans the rest, this is a nice combination between allowing html rendering and preventing evil tags, you can read about the sanitize helper [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)

Sanitizing a `nil` object returns `nil`, I would say it's safe because the `puts` will call `#to_s` on the `nil` object, which would convert `nil` to an empty string.

```
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
  <%= sanitize ev.details %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: and i almost didn't give you the answer award, Well done good sir, Exactly what i needed and helps others :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw` method [Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw)

```
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
  <%= raw(ev.details) %>
<% end %>
```