# What would the reason be for my ckeditor to output html tags onto the screen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed ckeditor on my blog website I am building and whenever I create a new post using ckeditor, the post gets outputted blog with the html tags that were used during the post creation.

So if I bold a text, the strong tag shows up on the screen but the text doesn't actually get bolded.

My new.html.erb shows:

```
<h1>Create Post</h1>

<%=  simple_form_for :lesson, url: lessons_path do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

    <%= f.input :content, :as => :ckeditor, input_html: {:ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'FULL'}}, class: "form-control" %></div>



<p>
<%= f.submit :Submit！ %>
</p>


<% end %>
```

My ckeditor settings are:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.language = 'en';
  config.width = '700';
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  config.toolbar_Pure = [
    '/', {
      name: 'basicstyles',
      items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
    }, {
      name: 'paragraph',
      items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']
    }, {
      name: 'links',
      items: ['Link', 'Unlink']
    }, '/', {
      name: 'styles',
      items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
    }, {
      name: 'colors',
      items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']
    }, {
      name: 'insert',
      items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak']
    }
  ];
  config.toolbar = 'Pure';
  return true;
};
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4052936/2231236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `html_safe` on the post text when you are displaying it

For ex if -

```
<div><%= post_data.html_safe %><div>
```

html_safe will not escape the HTML tags

Comment: Doesn't `html_safe` mark the string as trusted, so that **no** additional escaping happens? Thats what the OP wants but your explanation `html_safe will escape HTML tags` is would then be wrong?

Comment: @t.niese It was typo error. Thanx for correction (Y)